# Image Processing Algorithm design: how to get front images from an angled camera?

Tags: python, c++, algorithm, opencv, image-processing

Hi and thanks for noticing my problem! Currently I have a reqiurement to adjust the input videostream by making it "frontal".

Here is the DESIRED frontal image

[image: the desired frontal image]

Here is the ACTUAL frame images from the input videostream

[image: input image]

The algorithm required, to my knowledge, should include basic location adjustment or even modeling, and some of the image information won't find a corresponding position in the new frame. However, it's rather difficult to design such an angle-removing algorithm on my own, and I failed to find any reference on Github. So can you offer me some algorithm that I can turn to or some clue? And is it also possible to "add an angle" on a frontal image?

Much thanks! I really prefer python though the language suffers heavy "computational complexity" problem in this case.

Comment: This question is way too broad to warrant any reasonable answer.

Comment: BTW I can't use MATLAB to solve this problem cuz I'm not allowed to :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The image must undergo a so-called homographic transform,

```
X = (a x + b y + c) / (g x + h y + 1)
Y = (d x + e y + f) / (g x + h y + 1)
```

This transform will map for instance the four corners of the screen in the input stream to four points in the destination image that form a rectangle with the correct aspect ratio.

Knowing the four correspondences between the corners, you establish a system of 8 equations in 8 unknowns, which can be written in a linear form.

Equipped with this transformation, you scan the destination image and for every pixel find the corresponding one in the source image, and copy the RGB values.

This is good enough for a low quality transform. To avoid jaggies, you can use a bilinear interpolation between the four neighboring pixels in the source.

Have a look here: https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.1/d9/dab/tutorial_homography.html

If you want to find the screen corners automatically, this is a whole other story.